# why read and write are the only abstract methods in InputStream and OutputStream

Tags: java, io

**Only** `read()` and `write(int x)` methods are `abstract` in [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) and [OutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html)?

So,why `read()` and `write(int x)` are the **only** abstract methods in `InputStream` and `OutputStream`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [Javadoc for InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) says,

> Applications that need to define a subclass of InputStream must always
>   provide a method that returns the next byte of input.

All the other methods (e.g. read multiple bytes) can be implemented using simply `read()`. i.e. if I provide an implementation to read from a new source (e.g. perhaps a new bit of hardware) I simply need to provide the means to read a single byte. The `InputStream` provides all the other mechanisms around this.

Note that the other methods *aren't* `final`. So subclasses can provide more efficient implementations of (say) reading multiple bytes, but they don't *have* to.

The same would apply for `OutputStream`